# Proyection don't works with sort in sails

Tags: sails.js, waterline

Why when use sort in sails, don't works proyections.

```
Command.find({},{parameter:true, value: true, _id: false, finalDate:true}).sort('finalDate ASC').exec(function(error, cmd){}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo/issues/53) is answer

> When you use Sort() this disable proyection.

When you use Waterline you are not interacting directly with the sails-mongo driver. Waterline is an adapter agnostic abstraction that allows adapters to be built using a specific interface.

The current find method only takes a criteria object and not a projection object. This is because the find method in Waterline must work with not only sails-mongo but also sails-mysql, sails-postgresql, sails-redis, etc.

In the next Waterline release, 0.10, I want to introduce a select option to the query builder to allow this sort of thing to be accomplished across all adapters.

In the meantime if you want projections you have access to the direct mongo driver by using the native method:

// Grab an instance of the mongo-driver

```
User.native(function(err, collection) {
    // Execute any query that works with the mongo js driver
    collection.find(criteria, projection).sort(sort).toArray(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(users);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Where did you find `projections` documentations? AFAIK, `projections` is not available in Waterline.

Comment: you wrong if you run that query without sort, works perfectly. in find the projection parameter specifies which fields to return. The parameter contains either include or exclude specifications, not both, unless the exclude is for the _id field